# Get Large Query PostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql

I got some problems with my query in Postgres database.

My query is like this :

```
Filter1 <- unique(data1$col1)
query <- paste0(paste0("$", seq_along(Filter1)), collapse=", ")
query <- paste0("SELECT *
                 FROM action
                 WHERE col2 IN (", query, ")")
action <- dbGetQuery(conn, query, as.list(Filter1))
```

And I got this error

> Error: Failed to retrieve query result metadata: lost synchronization with server: got message type "t", length 422658

Edit :

```
   Filter3 <- unique(data1$col1)
   query <- glue_sql("SELECT * FROM action WHERE col2 IN 
                       ({Filter3*})",
                       .con = conn)
    
   action <-  dbGetQuery(conn, query)
```

Comment: (1) `Filter` is a poor choice for a variable, since there is a `Filter()` function in base R. (2) Instead of using `paste0` for creating a query and being valnurable to possible injections, you should consider using `glue_sql`. See https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/

Comment: These two query works but the one with glue_sql takes several time and I don't know why

Comment: Do you still get an error?

Comment: No more errors with glue_sql but it takes a long time to run even for a simple query where paste0 takes 10 seconds